# UIBackButton background not functioning?

Tags: ios, render

My back button in my app works perfectly on Retina-based devices but has serious issues on non-Retina devices. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening? As you can see the UINavigationBar background gets overlayed on top of the text area of the button.
However, when viewed on a Retina device, it renders correctly. Both images have @2x versions for retina display but for some reason the standard version won't render. I use this code to set the background button's image:

> ```
> UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutt4on.png"];
> [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
> ```

Non-Retina:
[image]

Retina:
[image]

Comment: Are you testing this on iOS 6 or lower?

Comment: It happens on the iOS 6.0 simulator on Xcode 4.5, but still happens on a 5.1.1 iPhone 3GS I test on.

Comment: By the way, thank you for reformatting, I couldn't add the images because of low post count.